# AWS-Logs, ElasticSearch : Logs not showing up in Kibana from AWS-Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatch

I am streaming AWSLogs to CLoudwatch and from there, I am streaming it on ElasticSearch domain. I can see in the overview, that I have a heck number of searchable documents, but I am not able to find the documents when I am searching them in Kibana. I will explain how I am doing it, maybe some idea what am I doing wrong. Thank you.

Installed AWSLogs service from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html)
Commands :

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -O
sudo python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py --region OUR_REGION
```

Once that's done, I added in `/var/awslogs/etc/awslogs.conf` my log files in such manner :

```
[/var/www/html/var/log/exception.log]
datetime_format = %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S
file = /var/www/html/var/log/exception.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = staging.1c.APP_NAME.exception.log
initial_position = end_of_file
log_group_name = staging.1c.APP_NAME.exception.log
```

I am able to see the stream-names in CloudWatch, and from actions there I am streaming it to ElasticSearch, but when I go in discover in Kibana and search for `_type:staging`, I get no results. What am I doing wrong? I also extended the time-criteria, but no luck.

*Update*

for get indices, I have

```
health status index          uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
    yellow open   cwl-2019.09.14 1xN0jOitQ-GAW7L3zFtiwQ   5   1      78590            0     55.4mb         55.4mb
```

So, I created an index-pattern with name  cwl-2019.09.14, but still can't get results.

Comment: Do you insert the data to a new index? if so, please check: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html

Comment: @AmitBaranes : Actually, I am just selecting option from AWS to stream it to AWS ElasticSearch....it's an option available in CloudWatch logs....

Comment: yeah but you still need to define the index in the kibana

Comment: @AmitBaranes : Hi, Please check updated question. I created an index-pattern, still no luck....